# Colored sectors with one or two loop(s)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[fill=red] (0,0)--(0:6) arc (0:60:6)--cycle;
        \draw[fill=white] (0,0)--(0:5) arc (0:60:5)--cycle;
        \draw[fill=green] (0,0)--(0:3.5) arc (0:60:3.55)--cycle;
        
        \draw[fill=red] (0,0)--(60:6) arc (60:120:6)--cycle;
        \draw[fill=green] (0,0)--(60:5) arc (60:120:5)--cycle;
        \draw[fill=white] (0,0)--(60:3.5) arc (60:120:3.55)--cycle;
        
        \draw[fill=white] (0,0)--(120:6) arc (120:180:6)--cycle;
        \draw[fill=green] (0,0)--(120:5) arc (120:180:5)--cycle;
        \draw[fill=red] (0,0)--(120:3.5) arc (120:180:3.55)--cycle;
        
        \draw[fill=white] (0,0)--(180:6) arc (180:240:6)--cycle;
        \draw[fill=red] (0,0)--(180:5) arc (180:240:5)--cycle;
        \draw[fill=green] (0,0)--(180:3.5) arc (180:240:3.55)--cycle;
        
        
        \draw[fill=green] (0,0)--(240:6) arc (240:300:6)--cycle;
        \draw[fill=red] (0,0)--(240:5) arc (240:300:5)--cycle;
        \draw[fill=white] (0,0)--(240:3.5) arc (240:300:3.55)--cycle;
        
        \draw[fill=green] (0,0)--(300:6) arc (300:360:6)--cycle;
        \draw[fill=white] (0,0)--(300:5) arc (300:360:5)--cycle;
        \draw[fill=red] (0,0)--(300:3.5) arc (300:360:3.55)--cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

that has this output:

[image]

**Question**: it is possible to have the same output with one or two loop(s)?

**EDIT**: If You want each colored sector to have the same area (2pi), You need this 3 radii: 2sqrt(3), sqrt(24) and 6.

Comment: Are you intentional to set the nuance between 3.5 and 3.55?

Comment: @Stephen Sorry is just a typo! Read always 3.5. Sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like to use short specifications instead of spelling everything out which is why I employ some smart keys setup so that they automatically define another style which we can use on the paths.
This allows for the short loop list of `gnr, ngr, rgn, grn, nrg, rng` where `g` stands for green, `r` for red and `n` for none.

The `ring or pie` is only used once (because even the three rings can be put into a foreach loop) but I believe that key to be handy anyway … and the second document shows how we can use it to allow for more flexible drawings without having to change much code.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  set colors/.style n args={3}{
    /tikz/@set color/#1={1}, /tikz/@set color/#2={2}, /tikz/@set color/#3={3}},
  /utils/temp/.style 2 args={@set color/#1/.style={/tikz/color ##1/.style={fill=#1#2}}},
  /utils/temp/.list={red, green, none}}
\begin{document}
\tikz[
  ring or pie/.style n args={3}{
    insert path={   (60*#1   :#3) arc[forward =#1, radius=#3]
                 -- (60*#1+60:#2) arc[backward=#1, radius=#2] -- cycle}},
  forward/.style={start angle=60*#1, delta angle=60},
  backward/.style={end angle=60*#1, delta angle=-60}]
\foreach[count=\i from 0] \c in {gnr, ngr, rgn, grn, nrg, rng}
  \foreach[
    /tikz/set colors/.expand once=\c, count=\j,
    remember=\r as \prevR (initially 0)]\r in {3.5, 5, 6}
    \draw[color \j, ring or pie={\i}{\prevR}{\r}];
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

We can extend this approach for more than three colors and more than a wheel with six pies.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, shadings}
\tikzset{
  new color shortcut/.style n args={3}{
    #1 color/#2/.style={/tikz/use #1 color/##1/.style={#3}}},
  set color shortcuts/.style 2 args={% draw and text, too
    new color shortcut={draw}{#1}{draw={#1#2}},
    new color shortcut={text}{#1}{text={#1#2}},
    new color shortcut={fill}{#1}{fill={#1#2}}},
  /utils/temp/.style={
    use #1 color/.is choice,
    #1 colors/.code=
      \def\pgfmathcounter{0}\pgfkeysalso{/tikz/@#1 colors={##1\relax}},
    @#1 colors/.code 2 args={%
      \edef\pgfmathcounter{\pgfinteval{\pgfmathcounter+1}}%
      \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/#1 color/##1=\pgfmathcounter}%
      \ifx##2\relax\else\pgfkeysalso{/tikz/@#1 colors={##2}}\fi}},
  /utils/temp/.list={draw, fill, color},
  wheel of rings and pies/.style={
    forward/.style={start angle=360/#1*##1, delta angle= 360/#1},
    backward/.style={end  angle=360/#1*##1, delta angle=-360/#1},
    ring or pie/.style n args={3}{insert path={(360/#1*##1:##3)
      arc[forward=##1, radius=##3] --(360/#1*##1+360/#1:##2)
      arc[backward=##1, radius=##2] -- cycle}}}}
\begin{document}
\tikz[wheel of rings and pies=6, set color shortcuts/.list={red, green, none}]
\foreach[count=\i from 0] \c in {gnr, ngr, rgn, grn, nrg, rng}
  \foreach[
    /tikz/fill colors/.expand once=\c, count=\j,
    remember=\r as \prevR (initially 0)]\r in {3.5, 5, 6}
    \draw[use fill color/.expanded=\j, ring or pie={\i}{\prevR}{\r}];
\tikz[
  wheel of rings and pies=24,
  set color shortcuts/.list={yellow, cyan, magenta},
  new color shortcut=
    {fill}{X}{preaction={ball color=gray}, pattern=bricks, pattern color=black}]
\foreach[count=\i from 0]\c in {ycmX, cymX, mycX, ymcX, cmyX, mcyX,
  mcXy, cmXy, Xmcy, mXcy, cXmy, Xcmy, Xymc, yXmc, mXyc, Xmyc, ymXc, myXc,
  cyXm, ycXm, Xcym, cXym, yXcm, Xycm}
  \foreach[
    /tikz/fill colors/.expand once=\c, count=\j,
    remember=\r as \prevR (initially 0)]\r in {1, 2, 3, 4}
    \draw[use fill color/.expanded=\j, ring or pie={\i}{\prevR}{\r}];
\end{document}
```

### Output (only 2nd diagram)

[image]

Comment: Very well! You are a devil!

Comment: Well deserved suggestion

Answer (score 4):

After some reflections about the Qrrbrbirlbel's answer I have a short solution to my question with one loop (4 variables):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \ang/\c/\d/\f in {0/green/white/red,60/white/green/red,120/red/green/white,180/green/red/white,240/white/red/green,300/red/white/green}{%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\Ang}{\ang+60}
            \draw[fill=\f] (0,0)--(\ang:6) arc (\ang:\Ang:6)--cycle;
            \draw[fill=\d] (0,0)--(\ang:4.9) arc (\ang:\Ang:4.9)--cycle;
            \draw[fill=\c] (0,0)--(\ang:3.464) arc (\ang:\Ang:3.464)--cycle;
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output show also the same area for all the sectors (not requested):

[image]

Comment: The preceding solution, however, is more suitable to show all the permutations of 4 or more colors.

Comment: I didn't even realize that it shows all permutations. :D

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I made reference to your solution, It is more general. My solution and your solution can shoew the 6 permutations of 3 colors. Yours (not myne) can show all the permutations of more that 3 colors.